# How to validate rules in request for update? laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, validation, request

ProductRequest:

```
 public function rules()
    {
        return [
            //
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'category_id' => 'required|integer',
            'price' => 'required|min:500',
            'quantity' => 'required|integer|min:1',
            'details' => 'required',
            'description' => 'required',
            'additional' => 'required',
        ];
    }
```

But the problem is that only works when Im creating new product, when Im updating it and removing all fields, it doesn't trigger. How to validate these fields when Im updating product?

Comment: From where you are calling this function, post that code to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works for any request, you just need to use `ProductRequest` in both `update()` and `store()` methods:

```
public function update(ProductRequest $request)
```